# QSortFilterProxyModel and setDynamicSortFilter

Tags: c++, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm developing an application with `Qt 5.12.4`. I have subclassed from `QSortFilterProxyModel` and called

```
    myModel->setDynamicSortFilter(true)
```

cause during the model exists I add new rows to it's source model.

But while debugging I found out that after adding a new row to the source model the proxy model doesn't refilter...As far as I understand that's what `setDynamicSortFilter` should do. Am I wrong?
Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. When adding new rows to the source model I call `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows`.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: dynamicSortFilter is `true` by default since Qt 5.0, so the call shouldn’t even be necessary. It needs an example here indeed.